# How to set a column value equal to the value in another table?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update

I am trying to figure out how to update a row in one table, setting a column value equal to a value in a different table. Here's an example:

```
movies:

movie_id | movie_price

movies_attended:

attended_id | attended_movie_id | attended_movie_price
```

Now, this is kind of a stupid example, but supposed that for some reason there is a row in movies_attended that does not have the correct attended_movies_price in it and so it needs to be updated.

How should a query be written to update the movies_attended table, setting movies_attended.attended_movie_price = movies.movie_price?

I tried something similar to the following, but it did not work:

```
update movies_attended, movies 
set movies_attended.attended_movie_price = movies.movie_price 
where movies_attended.attended_movie_id = movies.movie_id 
AND attended_id = [the id of the row we want to update]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "it did not work", do you mean that it reported 0 rows updated, or did the statement cause the database raise an exception?

Your example statement appears to be of the form:

```
UPDATE movies_attended a
  JOIN movies m
    ON a.attended_movie_id = m.movie_id
   SET a.attended_movie_price = m.movie_price
 WHERE a.attended_id = ?
```

(We typically prefer the `JOIN ... ON ...` style syntax to the comma join operator and the join predicates in the WHERE clause.)

I have no explanation as to why this statement would "not work".

It's possible this would report 0 rows affected, if no rows satisfy the predicates. It would also report 0 rows affected if the rows that would be changed do not require any changes... that is, the existing value in `attended_movie_price` already matches the value being assigned to it.

Normally, before running an update statement like that, I write it as a SELECT first, and see what values are returned...

By replacing the `UPDATE` keyword with `SELECT ... FROM`, and removing the `SET` clause:

```
SELECT m.movie_price          AS new_val
     , a.attended_movie_price AS old_val
     , a.attended_id
  FROM UPDATE movies_attended a
  JOIN movies m
    ON a.attended_movie_id = m.movie_id
 WHERE a.attended_id = ?
```

Comment: Yes, it said "0 rows affected." Tried your alternative syntax, but it said the same thing.

Comment: I take that back, it does work! A mistake on my part.. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bad database design. You don't need movie price in two tables.

But, if you just need this, it goes something along this:

```
UPDATE movies_attended
INNER JOIN
movies
ON movies_attended.attended_movie_id = movies.movie_id
SET movies_attended.attended_movie_price = movie.movie_price
```

Comment: In my application I actually do, as the base price varies over time. I did not try your solution because it does not update a single row. It appears as though it would update all rows.

Comment: This is not necessarily a bad database design, it may be that the `movies` table contains the current standard price, and that the `movies_attended` table contains a historical price, the price in effect at the time the movie was attended. In this case, it's not a bad database design, but it would be a mistake to assume that EVERY row in `movies_attended` would have a price that matches the current `price` in the `movies` table.

Comment: I misunderstood you, sorry. You just add WHERE movies_attended.attended_movie_id = * at the end of the statement, replacing a star with an actual movie id